# Android JNI: loadlibrary from install dir only

Tags: android, android-ndk

So, currently there is no way on Android, but to manually preload dependent shared libs. That's fine with me, not a big deal.
There is also some problem with android buildsystem (prebuild libraries feature), and for that reason I had to name differently different builds of my dependent shared library: **libsal.so** and **libsal-slim.so**. Depending on build settings one of these two makes it into the final apk. Then, on java side, I try to load libsal.so and if it fails, then I try to load libsal-slim.so.

It worked all fine, until we stumbled upon a phone that ships that libsal.so in default firmware installed into /system/lib. For that reason, my app stopped working on that phone if it's built with libsal-slim.so, since it tries to load libsal.so first and it loads wrong library from /system/lib.

Question: how can I ensure that only library from my install folder gets loaded? Maybe I can somehow retrieve install folder of my app and "calculate" full path of my shared lib? How can I do that java voodoo magic? I'm big time noob in java and android in general, if this questions looks too naive :) and yes, I don't speak English (or how they say), please rely in c++ [end-of-joke]

libsal.so isn't actual name, I used it only for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `System.load(fullpath_of_the_lib)`can probably solve your problem.

But your problem is to get the fullpath_of_the_lib. In fact the android API don't allow you to get the path of a resource. You can only get a stream to read it.

To workaround this limitation, what you can do is the following:

- put your lib in your app assets folder.
- open a InputStream on your lib : `getAssets().open("libsal.so")`
- create a file named "libsal.so" (or whatever) in your sdcard
- copy bytes from the inputstream to the file just created
- get the absolute filepath of your "libsal.so" on the sdcard
- call `System.load(fullpath_of_the_lib_on_the_sd_card)`

Of course you only need the last step in the lib is already on the sdcard.

An simpler alternative is maybe renaming your lib to something like libMyVeryUncommonLibraryName.so so that it won't conflict with another library name.